# Extend a crud-repository interface to handle JPA and mongo entities using spring-data

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, spring-data, repository

I have an application that currently uses relational DBs but could later move on to NoSQL DBs. In this case, I am trying to build my POJOs in such a way that it could be used for both type of DBs (relational and NoSQL). I have the following entities as defined below.

Base class:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
public abstract class SpringDataUser implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected long id;
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String middleInitial;
protected String email;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMiddleInitial() {
    return middleInitial;
}

public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("User ==> ");
    sb.append("id = " + id + "; ");
    sb.append("suemail = " + email + "; ");
    sb.append("lastname = " + lastName + "; ");
    sb.append("firstname = " + firstName + "; ");
    sb.append("middleInitial = " + middleInitial);

    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

JPA class:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.jpa;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.SpringDataUser;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "spring_data_user")
public class SpringDataUserJpa extends SpringDataUser {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
@Id
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "last_name")
@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "email")
@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public void setEmail(String suemail) {
    this.email = suemail;

}

@Column(name = "first_name")
@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "middle_initial")
@Override
public String getMiddleInitial() {
    return middleInitial;
}

@Override
public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
}
}
```

Mongo Class:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.mongo;

import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.SpringDataUser;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "spring_data_users")
public class SpringDataUserMongo extends SpringDataUser {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;

}

@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Override
public String getMiddleInitial() {
    return middleInitial;
}

@Override
public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
}
}
```

I am planning to build a DAO to access records using these entities. I would like to define a generic DAO and then extend that for different storage types as shown below.

Generic DAO:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SpringDataUserRepository<SpringDataUser> extends     PagingAndSortingRepository<SpringDataUser, Long> {
List<SpringDataUser> findByEmail(String email);

List<SpringDataUser> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

JPA DAO:

```
 package net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.jpa;

 import net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository;
 import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.jpa.SpringDataUserJpa;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Profile("jpa")
public interface SpringDataUserJpaRepository extends SpringDataUserRepository<SpringDataUserJpa> {
}
```

Mongo DAO:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.mongo;

import net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository;
import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.mongo.SpringDataUserMongo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
@Profile("mongo")
public interface SpringDataUserMongoRepository extends SpringDataUserRepository<SpringDataUserMongo>    {
}
```

As you have noticed, I am trying to get help from spring-data's automatic DAO implementation generation feature as defined below.

Application Context File:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx       
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


<!-- Load all the property files required in the App. Files with prefix 
    'override' are used to set properties based on the environment. -->
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:runway.properties" />

<bean id="tejasCarestationProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:conf/runwayidm.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.breezeware" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- NOTE: JNDI is NOT used to set DB properties. 'jdbc/AlstomDataSource 
    can be set in the context.xml file Tomcat's 'conf' directory. It was done 
    as an exercise to see if it works! -->
<!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="runwayDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/AlstomDataSource" 
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" /> -->

<bean id="runwayDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="runwayDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <!-- FIXME: Having the top level & wild cards in the package 
                value does not work. -->
            <!-- <value>net.breezeware.alstom.groupcontrol</value> -->
            <value>net.breezeware</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialectClass}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="net.breezeware" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


<!-- ######################### Mongo DB ######################### -->

<mongo:mongo host="${mongodb.host}" port="${mongodb.port}" />

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" host="${mongodb.host}"
    port="${mongodb.port}" dbname="${mongodb.dbname}" username="${mongodb.username}"
    password="${mongodb.password}" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have included the Service class that uses the DAO to access the stores:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository;
import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.SpringDataUser;
import net.breezeware.runway.idm.service.api.IdmService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class IdmServiceImpl implements IdmService {

@Autowired
SpringDataUserRepository<SpringDataUser> springDataUserRepository;

@Transactional
public SpringDataUser saveSpringDataUser(SpringDataUser user) {
    // return springDataUserRepository.save(user);
    return null;
}

@Transactional
public List<SpringDataUser> findSpringDataUsersByLastName(String lastName) {
    return springDataUserRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
}

@Transactional
public List<SpringDataUser> findAllSpringDataUsers() {
    return (List<SpringDataUser>) springDataUserRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

I have the following Application file that serves as the entry point to the App:

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class IdmApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdmApplication.class);

    SpringApplication.run(IdmApplication.class, args);

    logger.info("Inside main method of IdmApplication");

}
}
```

Here is he code I have to test the service functionality.

```
package net.breezeware.runway.idm;

import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.SpringDataUser;
import net.breezeware.runway.idm.entity.jpa.SpringDataUserJpa;
import net.breezeware.runway.idm.service.api.IdmService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:**/applicationContext.xml"})
// @EnableAutoConfiguration
// @ComponentScan
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"jpa"})
// @WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = IdmApplication.class)
public class IdmServicesJpaTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdmServicesJpaTest.class);

@Autowired
private IdmService idmService;

@Test
public void createSpringDataUserTest() {
    logger.info("========== createSpringDataUserTest()  ==========");

    SpringDataUser user = new SpringDataUserJpa();
    try {
        user.setId(1);
        user.setEmail("mark@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("mark");
        user.setLastName("adams");
        user.setMiddleInitial("");

        logger.info("SpringDataUser to be saved = " + user);

        SpringDataUser savedUser = idmService.saveSpringDataUser(user);
        logger.info("Saved User = " + savedUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Exception Occured = " + e);
    }
}
}
```

I would like to use the 'Profile' feature in Spring to choose the DAO implementation in run-time. I expect the code to work, but unfortunately I have trouble getting the DAO interfaces to be autowired into Service classes. It seems like the DAO/Repository implementations for the SpringDataUserRepository is not not created by Spring-Data. Here is the error in my log file when I try to run the test.

```
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'idmServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository net.breezeware.runway.idm.service.impl.IdmServiceImpl.springDataUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository net.breezeware.runway.idm.service.impl.IdmServiceImpl.springDataUserRepository; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.breezeware.runway.idm.dao.SpringDataUserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 55 more


I just could not get the DAOs instantiated/autowired into the Service class. I have tried different settings like marking the base entity Object 'SpringDataUser' with @MarkedSuperclass and such, but nothing seems to work.

Please let me know if I am missing something. I have spent a considerable amount of time on StackOverflow to find an answer but could not find one that solves my problem.
```

Thanks in advances.